# how to keep loader for xamarin c# while calling webservice

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I wanted to keep loader for xamarin forms is there a way to keep loader in PCL file rather than keeping separately in android and ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few options:

- You can use [ActivityIndicator](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/) which is an abstraction of a 'loader' on each platform.
   Just add `<ActivityIndicator IsRunning ="true" />` to your XAML.
- Another option is to use 'IsBusy' property of [Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/#Public_Properties). 
  So you could set it to true to activate global activity indicator on each platform.
- Additionally, there is a very handy open source library [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) which you can use to present an AcitivityIndicator as a popup, so you don't have to deal with disabling controls on your form.

Now when you know how to present a loading indicator on the screen, all you need to do is to bind 'IsRunning' (depends on the presenter) to a bool flag in your ViewModel.
Which will change its state according to your WebService call state.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you ! Works for me